How can one automatically check if a PDF contains a section with a specific title?

Task: I have several PDFs. How can one automatically check if a PDF contains a section with a specific title?
Environment: I can use Windows, or command line on Ubuntu.
Motivation: https://aclrollingreview.org/cfp#limitations "Authors are required to discuss the limitations of their work in a dedicated section titled “Limitations”." I need to check that, as well as other sections.
Example: this PDF has a section titled “Limitations”.


Are you specifically looking only for a section, or just for the presence of specific text?

@music2myear specifically looking only for a section title. Example: this PDF has a section titled “Limitations”. It shouldn't look at text that isn't a section title.

I ran this from Linux Mint, which is based on ubuntu:
search_string="Limitations"; if pdftotext -layout -raw -nopgbrk 2407.04855 - | grep -e "^${search_string}$" ; then echo "Yup, found ${search_string}"; else echo "Nope, did not find ${search_string}" ; fi

Here is some output:
me@comp tmp $ search_string="Limitations"; if pdftotext -layout -raw -nopgbrk 2407.04855 - | grep -e "^${search_string}$" ; then echo "Yup, found ${search_string}"; else echo "Nope, did not find ${search_string}" ; fi
Limitations
Yup, found Limitations
me@comp tmp $ search_string="Some Random Heading"; if pdftotext -layout -raw -nopgbrk 2407.04855 - | grep -e "^${search_string}$" ; then echo "Yup, found ${search_string}"; else echo "Nope, did not find ${search_string}" ; fi
Nope, did not find Some Random Heading
me@comp tmp $ search_string="Abstract"; if pdftotext -layout -raw -nopgbrk 2407.04855 - | grep -e "^${search_string}$" ; then echo "Yup, found ${search_string}"; else echo "Nope, did not find ${search_string}" ; fi
Abstract
Yup, found Abstract
me@comp tmp $ search_string="1 Introduction"; if pdftotext -layout -raw -nopgbrk 2407.04855 - | grep -e "^${search_string}$" ; then echo "Yup, found ${search_string}"; else echo "Nope, did not find ${search_string}" ; fi
1 Introduction
Yup, found 1 Introduction
me@comp tmp $ search_string="2.3 Annotation Process"; if pdftotext -layout -raw -nopgbrk 2407.04855 - | grep -e "^${search_string}$" ; then echo "Yup, found ${search_string}"; else echo "Nope, did not find ${search_string}" ; fi
2.3 Annotation Process
Yup, found 2.3 Annotation Process

